# Load UIViewcontroller into a scrollView smaller than screen?

Tags: ios, swift

My `scrollView` size is smaller than the screen size in height (80% of height).
I would like to load into it a few `UIViewControllers`.

Later, when I try to use the `view.height` of that `viewController`, it still has the size of a full screen and not the size of the scroller.

I would like to be able to load this controller into my scroller and make it the size of that scroller, so `view.height` will be 80% of screen, and not the original controller height, so I can position things in the right way.

EDIT:

```
           controller1  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

            var frm = view.frame
            frm.origin.x=CGFloat(count)*view.frame.width
            frm.origin.y=0
            frm.size.height=scrollView.frame.height
            controller1.view.frame=frm
            scrollView.addSubview(controller1.view)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding height constraint to your viewcontroller's view ? I definitely recommend this blog post https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Answer (score 2):

You can only achieve this by using below concept.

Let your UIScrollView is in `MainVC`. Now here you wanted to add few UIViewControllers.

1. If you wanted to this from `storyboard`

   - Take a `containerView`
   - give it autolayout
   - assign the required `UIViewController`.
   - reference - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/
2. If you wanted to this by `code`

   - Create a child `VC`
   - add it in your `MainVC`
   - give the frame as per your requirement.
   - reference - https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Adding-and-Removing-Child-View-Controllers

> Description

In both the case actually you making the `MainVC` as a parentVC and then creating its childs. Whenever your `MainVC` is loaded is loads your child VC also can set the frame of `childVC` as per your requirment.

To pass the data from **Parent to child**, you can directly do this by assigning variables. But while passing the data from **Child to parent** you need to use `protocol-delegate` or `NSNotification`.

Still something unclear then ask.

Comment: So when you create a navigation controller for example, it takes some space of the screen, so when you set VCs into it, do they automatically get the new screen height? or do you have to set their frame like in your answer?

Comment: @Curnelious `childVC` only take height that you give n `parentVC` have the  usual hieght. For your more info `ChildvC` have no navigationController so to navigate from `childVC` you have to come back to `parentvc` n then navigate

Comment: your solution will actually not work. I set the VC.frame.height to be the scroller height, and when I read the child VC size I get the full screen size.

Comment: @Curnelious Definately you done something wrong. check this [tutorial](https://naveenr.net/beginning-container-views-in-ios/).